# I am a car. What is the car?

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

There's a car that exists. If you take off the first and last letter it's still a word. If you take off the first and last letter again it's still a word. If you take off the first and last letter again it's still a word. What is the car?

Comment: is it a brand???

Comment: Did not say make or model..... :/

Comment: okay then. Welcome to puzzling!

Comment: @Teri what do you mean?

Comment: What do I mean about what?  Trying to help my niece out?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how that applied

Comment: @TrojanByAccident Teri is helping their niece solve the puzzle, they don't know any more about the puzzle than we do

Comment: This same puzzle was actually one of the Car Talk puzzlers a few years ago! http://www.cartalk.com/content/whats-cars-name?question

Comment: It would be interesting to right a computer program that finds words that meet this condition.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the correct answer as ✔ Accepted.

Answer (score 68):

The answer is

> The Mitsubishi **Eclipse**:
>
> ```
>  ECLIPSE
>   CLIPS
>    LIP
>     I
> ```

Comment: I was wondering why it didn't sound familiar, apparently it was never sold in Europe.

Comment: @Separatrix You're wrong, at least for Germany I can say, that this car was sold here ;).

Comment: aka the worst IDE of all time...I kid, sort of.

Comment: @Celeritas I actually get that joke. +1

Answer (score 38):

Using a [list of US models](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/n8barr/automotive-model-year-data/master/data.sql) and a [list of classic cars](http://www.classicandsportscar.com/guides/classic-cars-a-to-z/list), a python script, and a big list of words from [SCOWL](http://wordlist.aspell.net/) I get 6 answers including the one already given, but some rely on words consisting of a single consonant so are pushing it, while others, although the words appear in SCOWL, don't really appear to have English definitions (or only as names):

> avenger venge eng n
>
> classic lassi ass s
>
> eclipse clips lip i
>
> atalanta talant alan la
>
> trident riden ide d
>
> variant arian ria i (the Variant was a 70s VW)

The last is the only one I consider a *true* additional answer.

Definitions of the non-obvious words:

> [Venge](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/venge) archaic: avenge
>
> [Eng](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eng) the same as engma (IPA ŋ)
>
> [Lassi](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lassi) an Indian drink
>
> Talant: I'm not sure what it's doing in SCOWL, it appears only as Welsh, French and a proper noun.
>
> Alan is no better
>
> [Riden](https://www.wordnik.com/words/riden) An obsolete preterit plural of ride (n).
>
> [Ide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ide_(fish)) a fish, common in cryptic crosswords
>
> [Arian](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/arian) Relating to the doctrine, taught by Arius, that Christ the Son was not consubstantial with God the Father.
>
> D, N and S could be deuterium, nitrogen and sulphur, or the names of the letters.

Note that I excluded anything with digits or spaces in. Here's the script if anyone wants a play (but you might have to lose some of the set-formatting depending on your words file).  I also piped it through `sort` and `uniq`:

```
import re
words = set(open("words.txt").read().split())
words = set([w.split("/")[0] for w in words])
with open('cars2.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line =line[:-1].lower()
        if re.match('^[a-z]{7,}$',line):
            a,b,c=line[1:-1],line[2:-2],line[3:-3]
            if line in words and a in words and b in words and c in words:
                print line, a,b,c
```

Comment: Very smart way to find the answers!

Comment: @Melkor I'd done something similar recently, looking for words containing a group of letters for a project name, so the code and big word list were (much) easier than finding the lists of car names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I never knew about SCOWL but it seems really useful...

Comment: @Melkor I'm not the only one to use it here

Comment: what's "n", "s", and "d"? I've never seen these words before

Comment: @Cruncher that's why I'm not too happy with those sets and only propose *variant* (even though I don't know who made it) as a new answer. SCOWL has those 3 single letters as words, and I make some guesses as to why in my second  spoiler.

Comment: @ChrisH Lol, I skimmed it several times looking for reference to n, s, and d and it looked to me like you ignored it, which is why I commented. I see it now though :)

Comment: @Cruncher back on the desktop I can see why it's a little buried

Comment: an IDE in the context of programming is also known as an "integrated design environment".

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I've only heard it spelt out as an initialism (and it's the sort of thing that does come up in conversation where I work). So even if acronyms were OK here I wouldn't count IDE. How do you pronounce it?

Comment: @ChrisH what do you mean by "pronounce"? It's an acronym. You don't pronounce it...

Comment: @TheGreatDuck you've just defined an initialism (first example Google gives me is BBC). An acronym is normally pronounced as a word (e.g. NATO, LASER - the latter is normally treated as a normal word). IDE spelt out is no more a word than BBC. But if it sounded like *eyed* it could be treated as one word if it was sufficiently well known

Answer (score 37):

An alternative solution to the other posted, even though I think the existing one is "better"...

> A **[Mclaren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McLaren_Automotive)**
>
>  **[Clare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clare)** is a county in the Republic of Ireland, as well as the name of other places, and is also a forename (yes, a proper name hence the "better" comment above).
>  **[Lar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lar_gibbon)** is the common gibbon, as well as a [place name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAR) in both India and Iran.
>  **[A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)#Indefinite_article)** is the indefinite article.

Comment: a clever answer!

Comment: A is **'an'** indefinite article.

Comment: @boboquack He he, I see what you did there! I guess it's debatable though, since one could just say that the *form* (a/an/some) of *the* indefinite article to be used in an English sentence is prescribed by the rest of that sentence.

Comment: @boboquack Sentence could also be interpreted to how you could refer to Mike Meyers as the actor. "I met Mike Meyers", "Who?", "You know, the actor".

Answer (score 10):

Note: I'm new to this site and I looked on Meta for a post regarding loopholes and did not find anything regarding this. If this is considered 'not funny,' please let me know.

---

An alternative answer (but probably not the originally intended one) could also be

> Fiat 500, or any other car with only numbers is its model name, because there are no letters to remove. As the question is tagged 'wordplay', I thought it might be relevant.

Comment: But isn't 500 a bit too short to remove the outer characters three times?

Comment: @MOehm The joke would be that you can remove as many as you want, because there are no "letters". Again, this might be considered unfunny, but I didn't find this under the [standard loopholes](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/standard-loopholes). Maybe I missed it?

Comment: @Arc676 Some people might consider it breaking the second loophole. That loophole essentially is applying lateral thinking to a puzzle that doesn't have that tag.

Comment: 500 not a word?

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Fair point, but (and I'm really stretching things here) the New Oxford American Dictionary definition for "word" doesn't specify that it has to consist of letters. But I do agree that it's validity as a word is debatable.

Comment: 500 is a number, five hundred is two words

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Feel free to downvote as you see fit. I'll let the overall vote count reflect its validity.

Answer (score 1):

*The answer is:*

> **The Mitsubishi Eclipse.**

This is how:

> Eclipse
>  Clips
>  Lip
>  I

Comment: That's great.  Why does this answer look [very familiar](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48173/30633)?  (this answer has already been given.)  Welcome to Puzzling SE, you may want to look around and read other answers to make sure you don't post a duplicate answer.